# Problem to compile bibtex with texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, overleaf

I'm writting my thesis with overleaf, but since I have large images it was given an error of time out, so I'm trying to compile with Texmaker.

With Texmaker, my references appears in the PDF as a question mark, I know that has something to do with bibtex, but I already did (from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number)):
latex
bibtex
latex
latex

Would someone help me? my bibtex file is called biba.bib but seems texmaker doesn't recognize it
This is the error I have:

> Process started
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) The top-level
> auxiliary file: main.aux The style file: humannat.bst I couldn't open
> database file biba.bib.bib ---line 624 of file main.aux :
> \bibdata{biba.bib : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I
> found no database files---while reading file main.aux Warning--I
> didn't find a database entry for "cockett2015simpeg" Warning--I didn't
> find a database entry for "assembly2015resolution" Warning--I didn't
> find a database entry for "dentith2014geophysics" Warning--I didn't
> find a database entry for "simpegwebsite" Warning--I didn't find a
> database entry for "krivochieva2002whole" Warning--I didn't find a
> database entry for "carrasquilla2007evaluating" Warning--I didn't find
> a database entry for "samtani2006soils" Warning--I didn't find a
> database entry for "lai2005surface" Warning--I didn't find a database
> entry for "park2007multichannel" Warning--I didn't find a database
> entry for "wathelet2005" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for
> "lopes2018joint" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for
> "erkan2008comparative" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for
> "macneill1980electrical"
>
> for "rashid2018experimental" Warning--I didn't find a database entry
> for "ertcastanheira" (There were 2 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

and this is a PrintScreen from my project and biba.bib file

[image]

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing your issue?

Comment: I'm new with texmaker, I was using Overleaf, so the only thing I did, was to download the project from overleaf and compile the main file in texmaker, as is shown in the image

Comment: Your image is unreadable, but from the error message,  you probably wrote `\bibliography{biba.bib}`, which is wrong if you compile the bibliography with `bibtex`. It should simply be `\bibliography{biba}`. If you use `biblatex `, the syntax is different.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!